# rsync syntax works in --dry-run but not for real

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, virtualbox, rsync

I am trying to `rsync` the contents of a directory on local machine, via `ssh`, to my virtualbox.

As I understand, the base syntax for this would be: `rsync -avzhe ssh [local directory path from root] [ip]:[directory path from root]`

ergo:

```
$ rsync -avzhe ssh /Users/user_name/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/ 192.168.1.216/home/user_name/dir_a/dir_b/dir_c/
```

My `--dry-run` puts out a good message:

```
building file list ...
12 files to consider
created directory 192.168.1.216/home/user_name/dir_a/dir_b/dir_c
# ect, etc, etc

sent 412 bytes  received 92 bytes  1.01K bytes/sec
total size is 173.42K  speedup is 344.08
```

My real attempt - no go:

```
building file list ...
12 files to consider
rsync: mkdir "/Users/user_name/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/192.168.1.216/home/user_name/dir_a/dir_b/dir_c" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/main.c(544) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Typo 2 times:

I forgot to use a `user@[ip]` in the destination directory, and I missed a ":" after the ip.